# does object.style.color only return rgb

Tags: javascript

environment: JavaScript
object.style.color returns something like 
`"rgb(255,0,0)"`
Is there another return format, like hex?

```
var colorvariable = document.getElementById('text1').style.color
```

Comment: It returns what it returns, I believe (although I may be wrong) that its browser specific.

Comment: does it return what it is set to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set:

```
document.getElementById('text1').style.color = '#000';
```

It will return `#000`.

However, if you set:

```
document.getElementById('text1').style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
```

It will return `rgb(0,0,0)`, so this returned value depends on the value that was set.

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get the color in RGB format and then convert to HEX. See this code:

```
var hexChars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var rgb = getComputedStyle(document.body).color.match(/\d+/g);
var r = parseInt(rgb[0]).toString(16);
var g = parseInt(rgb[1]).toString(16);
var b = parseInt(rgb[2]).toString(16);
var hex = '#' + r + g + b;
```

Comment: In chrome dev tools, this is what I found. Is it browser specific then.
document.getElementById("newId").style.color="#000000"

document.getElementById("newId").style.color
rgb(255, 255, 255)