# Hex not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

How is that this works
(div cirlcedecider2 has is styled "green")

```
function badge1(){
if (document.getElementById("circledecider2").style.color == "green"){

document.getElementById("badge1").style.backgroundColor= "#ABCF37";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.width = "200px";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.height = "200px";

}}
```

But this does not?
(div cirlcedecider2 has is styled "#ABCF37")

```
function badge1(){
if (document.getElementById("circledecider2").style.color == "#ABCF37"){

document.getElementById("badge1").style.backgroundColor= "#ABCF37";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.width = "200px";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.height = "200px";

}}
```

The only difference is using a hexcode.

Comment: Did you try using #abcf37 instead ?

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Comment: what is the color of circledecider2 ? Is it really GREEN or any other color?

Comment: It depends on what is set. See this please.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670019/does-object-style-color-only-return-rgb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference color](http://www.colorhexa.com/abcf37)

```
function badge1(){
if (document.getElementById("circledecider2").style.color == "rgb(171, 207, 55)")
{

document.getElementById("badge1").style.backgroundColor= "#ABCF37";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.width = "200px";
document.getElementById("badge1").style.height = "200px";

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

*#ABCF37* gets parsed and changed into a different format. The result is most likely browser specific.

```
document.body.style.color = "#ABCF37"
document.body.style.color; // "rgb(171, 207, 55)"
```

And obviously

```
"rgb(171, 207, 55)" == "#ABCF37"; // false
```

You will need to write some function to interpret the colours and return something standard you can compare against (possibly in a `rgba` format), or a function to compare two colours (which may be easier).

```
function compareColour(col1, col2) {
    var e = document.createElement('span')
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    // standardise
    e.style.color = col1;
    col1 = window.getComputedStyle(e).color;
    e.style.color = col2;
    col2 = window.getComputedStyle(e).color;
    // cleanup
    document.body.removeChild(e);
    return col1 === col2;
}

compareColour("#ABCF37", "rgb(171, 207, 55)"); // true
```

Comment: you are sure its guaranteed to return in the RGB or RGBA string format?

Comment: I feel it's browser specific

Answer (score 0):

The color you retrieve is **browser specific**.

In `IE` you can see the browser returning `hex` value, for that too your code should compare the alphabets in `hex` values in small case i.e. `#abcf37` in your case.

Other browsers like `chrome` return it in `rgb` format.

Alternate solution is to convert the value in hex format if returned in rgb.

Refer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value) for the alternate solution.